# Capture WPF window and send it TV source

Tags: algorithm, video-streaming, video-capture, broadcast, screen-capture

I am working on a WPF scoreboard project. I have created my dashboard. I am capturing my WPF window using with Chroma key technique with OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) and I can stream it over internet. Etc. Youtube.

I would like to use my same WPF project with TV source. I mean I would like to capture my WPF window and send it to TV source using PC HDMI output with alpha channel.

is it possible without using any hardware? If it is where will I start to learn?